# Analytic solution to stochastic differential equations

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

I need help to to find the analytic solution (if it exists) of the following system of SDE. Usually, I use Matlab as software but in this case I'm unable to use it in order to figure out the problem.
To begin with, $(\zeta_{t})$ is assumed to revert toward zero
following an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process; $(\xi_{t})$ is assumed to follow a Brownian motion
process
The system is as follows:
$$
d\zeta _{t}=(-\kappa \zeta _{t}-\varphi _{\zeta }-\phi _{\zeta }\xi
_{t})dt+\sigma _{\zeta }dz_{\zeta }
$$
$$
d\xi _{t}=(\mu _{\xi }-\varphi _{\xi }-\phi _{\xi }\zeta _{t})dt+\sigma _{\xi}dz_{\xi }
$$

$dz_{\zeta}$ and $dz_{\xi}$ are correlated increments of standard Brownian
motion process with $dz_{\zeta}dz_{\xi}=\rho_{\zeta\xi}dt$.

Can someone kindly help me? Or tell me how to solve analytically this system?
Many thanks in advance

Comment: @ Gammone Gammone : could you clarify your notations and specification of your problems please ? You mention $\zeta$ as an OU process but the SDE does not fit and  $\xi$  is simply not a BM. What are the details about $\phi,\varphi, \kappa,\mu$  ?Do they depend on time ?  For Brownian motions $z_{\zeta }$,and  $z_{\xi }$ it would be better to put an exponent on those and keep the index for time. Best regards.

Comment: @TheBridge:thanks 4 your reply. I'll try to be more clear (I hope!). The original process comes from a well-known model in derivatives pricing [link](https://goo.gl/yJhqzY). It assumes that a spot price can be seen as $ln(S_{t})=\zeta_{t}+\xi_{t}$ where $\zeta_{t}$ revert toward zero following an OU proc. and $\xi_{t}$ is assumed to follow a
BM proc. By adding some additional parameters you obtain a risk-neutral version. What I posted is just another interpretation of this model, but, in order to solve and understand it,I need to find the analytical solution.Hope this can helps,let me know. BR

Comment: Hi, after a quick review of the article there are still many unknowns left in your formulation. How do you get the intertwined system of SDE from the original system (meaning by that getting $\zeta$ and $\xi$ in each other SDES) ? Even in the RN formulation of the model there is no "intertwining" (eq. 7a and 7b of your reference). So can you add the line of argumentation to go from the the original model to this system of SDEs. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Hi fortunately your system of sde is a system of linear equation under the hypothesis that :
$\phi _{\zeta },\sigma _{\zeta },\phi _{\xi },\sigma _{\xi}, etc...$ are not random functions (they might depend on time ) and are locally bounded.

From Karatzas and Shreve Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus we known(section 5.6) that there is a solution for a linear system of SDEs.

So let's be given the following system d dimensional system (written in a vectorial formulation identical to the reference) :
$$dX_t=[A(t)X_t+a(t)]dt+ \sigma_t.dW_t$$
-$a(t)$ is a d dimensional vector function of time (non random measurable (in t) and locally bounded).
-$A(t)$ is a $d \times d$ matrix (non random measurable (in t) and locally   bounded).
-$W$ is a r dimensional Brownian motion.
-$\sigma(t)$ is $d \times r$ matrix (non random measurable (in t) and locally bounded).

Let's denote $\Phi$ the solution of the following ordinary matrix equation :
$$\Phi(t)'=A(t)\Phi(t)$$ with $\Phi(0)=Id$

Then : 
$$X(t) = \Phi(t).[X_0+\int_0^t \Phi(s)^{-1}.a(s).ds+\int_0^t \Phi(s)^{-1}.\sigma(s).dW_s]$$

Now what is left to to you is the calculation for which I have no personal interest but which seem tractable in your case.

PS: Even if the solution here is written in a framework where all component of W are independents, it's very easy to recast your framework in this setting with the proper matrix sigma (which is not diagonal).

Best regards

Comment: thank you so much for the time spent. This is very important to me, it will be my concern to carry out the calculations of what you've written. Best Regards

Comment: @Gammone Gammone : It would make the question more interesting if you derive the way you get to this system from the original one. Best regards.